# Catch submit event, validate and if o.k. continue to submit the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

It seems like something what supposedly looks very easy to implement is not possible.
I want to catch the submit event from a form and do some validation first. If the validation is done, I want to continue to submit the form.

```
$('#myform').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var valid = true;

  //- do some validation magic

  if(valid){
    $(this).submit();
    // $('#myform').submit(); // does not work as well
  }else{
    //- give feedback
        $('#error').fadeIn();
  }
})
```

That last part seems to be the issue; while triggering the submit event on the form when valid brings the script in an infinite loop.

Off course I can wrap everything in an AJAX call, but I prefer to just 'plain-simple' submit the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So only prevent the submission when it fails, there is no need to resubmit.

```
$('#myform').submit( function (e) {
    var valid = true;
    //- do some validation magic
    if (!valid) {
        $('#error').fadeIn();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh Sh*t offcourse just only preventDefault when it is necessary :(